# Reference request for mean curvature and extrinsic geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I am looking to further my intuition for mean curvature in higher dimensions, but am finding it hard to find online notes that don't just focus on the standard undergraduate curves & surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Could anyone recommend any lecture notes or books that treat concisely the notions of mean curvature, and the relations between the intrinsic and extrinsic curvatures for a general Riemannian submanifold?